# Why the ZeroMQ publisher binds to two endpoints?

Tags: zeromq

I am new to ZeroMQ and reading now about the publish-subscribe pattern.
Looking at the Java example here: http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:wuserver
Could someone explain why the publisher has to bind to two endpoints:

- tcp://*:5556
- ipc://weather

Is it mandatory to connect to more than one endpoint for this pattern to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I noticed that the publisher doesn't HAVE to bind to both endpoints.
My question is why the example that was provided in the guide uses the two endpoints? It is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It's just showing you that you can bind to multiple transports from the same socket. So if you changed your client to subscribe via `ipc://weather` connection and you were on the same host the communication would be more efficient.

You are correct though the examples give no mention of the dual bind or ipc so it is confusing if you are learning about zeromq.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the answer